# batch file to close cmd when program not found

Tags: python-3.x, batch-file

I am writing a python program which takes input from the user then create a batch file and open that program and I want that if program not found then it returns that error to python and close the popup

> ```
> Windows cannot find 'room'. make sure you type correctly, and then try again.
> ```

[image: error message]

and cmd.

I don't have any idea how to solve this problem.

```
def batch(text):

    bat_file = open("hello.bat","w")
    bat_file.write("start "+text)
    bat_file.close()
    os.startfile("hello.bat")
```

As I mentioned above I want to close the popup and cmd.

Comment: I'm a bit confused here, you used the keyword "start" in cmd. I thought you were trying to run a python program which would then execute a batch file? I'll take a look at your google drive link as soon as I'm on my home computer.

Comment: Yes when u run python program it writes a batch file and run that batch file after that content of batch file runs in cmd here "start programName " is content of batch file